# What is the difference between "etiquette", "courtesy", and "manners"?

Tags: meaning, differences

I found [this link](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090805192557AACscZD)
  explained the difference between "etiquette" and "courtesy", as following the rules and being kind to others. The answer regarded "etiquette" is similar with "manners"

If this link is correct, is there any difference between "etiquette" and "manners"? "etiquette" is more formal than "manners"?

Thank you very much

Comment: I've always considered the difference that etiquette is accepted convention for how you *should* act and manner is how you *do* act.

Comment: It might help also to know if you mean "manner" or "manners."  The latter seems more relevant to the rest of the question.  If it's "manner," then @JohnClifford has said it wonderfully well.

Comment: Singular ***manner*** simply means *the **way** in which [you act]* (it's a "neutral" term, implying nothing about whether people approve of how you do things). The *[good] etiquette* sense is always pluralized as *[good] **manners*** (or bad, since it's perfectly idiomatic to say *It's bad manners to talk with your mouth full*).

Comment: @Rob_Ster Thank you very much. I have edited it into plural form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Etiquette is following rules that govern behavior- it might be the reason that causes you to behave a certain way.

Courtesy is behaving in a way that benefits others- it means thinking of the effect of your behavior.

Your manner is how you behave, regardless of the cause or the effect.

Definitions from Collins Online Dictionary:

> [Etiquette](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/etiquette): the customs or rules governing behaviour regarded as correct or acceptable in social or official life
>
> [Courtesy](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/courtesy) is politeness, respect, and consideration for others.
>
> [Manner](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/manner): a person's bearing and behaviour

And to reiterate FumbleFinger's comment addressing *Manner* vs. *Manners*:

> [Manners](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/manners): a socially acceptable way of behaving

While your *manner* is how you behave, a comment on your *manners* is a judgment on how your behavior reflects on you, whether by how it conforms to etiquette or by how it effects the person making the judgment or others:

"It is bad manners to talk with your mouth full of food."

"Your child showed good manners at my child's party."

The [Yahoo Answer link](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090805192557AACscZD) that you asked about has a different view:

> the easiest of putting it is this (not true for all cases, but most): if you don't do something, and someone finds it rude, it deals with courtesy. if you do something, and someone finds it rude, it's etiquette

I don't think the error of commission vs. error of omission distinction is often the difference between courtesy and etiquette.

Comment: Fix the spelling of etiquette and you've earned my +1. ;)